# How do I solve "Error in View : object not found" in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, file, import, dataset

When I try to import dataset in R, it tells me this: "Error in View : object "GenomeTOT" not found" (where GenomeTOT is the name of the file). I can not understand why since I am importing the file directly from the environment so I choose it. How to solve this problem? The txt file has 3 columns and 55302 rows, so I do not know if it maybe a problem due to the size.

Comment: Show us all the code. We need to know how GenomeTOT is created.

Comment: I have no code. I simply click on "Import Dataset".I do not know how to attach the txt file here. It could be because there are too many tabs in the file ? I try to create it again.

Comment: Tbh I wouldn't know there's a feature called 'Import Dataset' if you didn't tell me. When you import the file, is there any message?

Comment: Yes, it is on the environment window and you can create your dataframe. Now I have solved the problem. The file had too much spaces so I have removed them and now I can import it without problems. Thank you @xwhitelight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you do not try to upload in coding way?
data <- read.delim("filename.txt")

Comment: Because I do not understand what I have to write inside the brackets each time. If I write as you suggest it tells me:Error in file (file, "rt"): I cannot open this connection
Also: warning message:
In file (file, "rt"):
  unable to open file "GenomeTOT.txt": no files or directories of this type.

Comment: I think I have to tell him the path of the file ? I do not know how to do so I usually use that straightforward method

Comment: Try first to set you directory and then to be sure that your file is inside there,  setwd("C:/folder")

Comment: Sorry Adam but I do not understand what I have to write in setwd() in order to change the directory ? Anyway with getwd() I have discovered that in fact I was working not in the same directory

Comment: The path of your folder. For example, your folder is in hard disc C:/ in D:/? You setting the folder, after you contain you file in the folder and then you write the two lines of code. setwd..... and then data<- read.delim etc.